# How does facebook comments plugin works?

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, comments

I would like to understand how the facebook comment plugin, that is inserted inside a web page, using a javascript script and a div tag, works.

If I try to guess (and using firebug), the javascript part loads an iframe that is inserted inside the div part.

My problem, is that everybody can put a comment feed that is not necessarily ralative to the web page content! Suggest I'm example.com, how can I be sure that example.org is not using my example.com facebook comments?

Does Disqus works similarily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would imagine that the script that loads the iframe or the iframe itself would do a check

Comment: For sure, but how? Javascript AJAX is executed from your machine, not from the original URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook url that is loaded within the IFRAME has access to the `REFERRER` URL (which is the loading page in this case) and uses it to check the domain.

Comment: Thank you Gil. I didn't know about `REFERRER` but its exactly what I was looking for.